# Layout view is in top left corner in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

Constraint layout is not well placed. It always views on top left corner, but in design view it shows in the whole display. I want to display the app in full screen mode.

This is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image]

Comment: Please include your layout here instead of a link to a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've set your 
`RelativeLayout` to a `layout_width` of 364dp and a `layout_height` of 494dp.  It looks fine on your preview because you are using a Nexus 4 (look above your preview) as your preview but you are testing with a emulated Nexus 5. Due to the fact that you've coded the resolution to be `364dp`x`494dp` (which is fine for a Nexus 4) your view will look different on different devices as they have difference screens. You should try changing your `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change width of `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` and set `layout_gravity` to `bottom`